# Overwrite displayed data with ajax fetched records

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to overwrite the current displayed records with all the records which I fetch using ajax request.

What I did initally in my controller is:

```
private ModelAndView fetchRecords(Model model) {


    model.addAttribute("records", getSelectedRecords());
    return new ModelAndView("list", "command", model);
}
```

and display the records in jsp as:

```
<c:forEach var="rec" items="${records}">
      ${rec}
</c:forEach>
```

It's working fine.

Now I map the ajax request like this in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list")
public @ResponseBody Object getServiceRequestSummaryPage(Model model, HttpSession session) {

    return records= getAllRecords();
}
```

Its returning the records to Jquery method below and showing in alert

```
function loadallRecords(pn){
    $.get("list.html", { pageNumber: pn }, function(records) {

        alert(records);
    });
}
<html>
<body>
<a href="" onClick="loadallRecords(${pn})" >Load all records</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I don't know how I can overwrite the selected records with all records in jsp.

I want to overwrite the below jsp with all records:

```
<c:forEach var="rec" items="${records}">
${rec}
</c:forEach>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In concept, you will use jQuery to find the container div that held your previous records (probably using an id value), you will call `.empty()` on it to clear out the previous records and then you will `.append()` your replacement records.

Since you've shown us none of the HTML for the records, we can't advise very specifically, but hypothetically, if the original page looked like this:

```
<div id="container">
<c:forEach var="rec" items="${records}">
      ${rec}
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Then, if loadallRecords is getting a JSON array of records, your replacement function could look like this:

```
function loadallRecords(pn){
    $.get("list.html", { pageNumber: pn }, function(records) {
        $container = $("#container");
        $container.empty();
        $.each(records, function(index, value) {
            $container.append(value);
        })
    });
}
```

If loadallRecords is getting an HTML string that represents the new results, then it would work like this:

```
function loadallRecords(pn){
    $("#container").load("list.html", { pageNumber: pn });
}
```

Comment: Could you please answer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447194/how-do-i-update-a-cforeach-using-ajax-in-spring-project   I don't know how to use your solution for mine.