# How do I update a c:forEach using Ajax in Spring project?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Following is the AJAX code where I select a value in dropdown and I get a List back from controller. When I get the list back, I want to update the c:forEach item using the AJAX result.

**AJAX**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#byCollege").change(function() {

            // Get and convert the data for sending
            // Example: This variable contains the selected option-text
            var collName = $('#byCollege').val();
            var studentName = '${salary}';
            var json = {"name" : studentName, "collName" : collName};

            // Send the data as an ajax POST request
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/AnnaUnivResults/mvc/byCollege",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:  JSON.stringify(json),
                contentType:  "application/json",
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    $("#studList").html(JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                error: function(data, status, er) {
                    alert("error: " + data + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {    
        alert(document.getElementById('studentName').val());
    }); 

    var current = document.getElementById('studentName').value();
    currnet.value = <c:out value="${salary}"/>
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
@ResponseBody @RequestMapping(value = "/byCollege", method = RequestMethod.POST,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  
    public List<OneStudentResult>   filterByColl(@RequestBody OneStudentResult oneStudentResult, ModelMap model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        String deptName = null;
        nameList = resultService.getStudentByColl(oneStudentResult.getName(), oneStudentResult.getCollName());

        Iterator<OneStudentResult> itr = nameList.iterator();

        Set<String> uniqueDeptList = new TreeSet<String>();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next().getName());
        }   

        uniqueDeptList.add(" Select a Department ");
        model.addAttribute("uniqueDeptList", uniqueDeptList);

        model.addAttribute("nameList", nameList);
        modelAndView.addObject("nameList", nameList);
        return nameList;
    }
    Set<String> uniqueDeptList = new TreeSet<String>();
    while(itr.hasNext()){

         deptName = itr.next().getDeptName();
         if(!uniqueDeptList.contains(deptName)){
            uniqueDeptList.add(deptName);
         }

    }   

    uniqueDeptList.add(" Select a Department ");
    model.addAttribute("uniqueDeptList", uniqueDeptList);

    model.addAttribute("nameList", nameList);
    return "nameResult";
}
```

Actually the purpose of the AJAX call is to update the   in jstl of jsp using AJAX.

PS: As of now I could see my old table going away and I see this my List as follows

```
[{"regNo":"1234","name":"ABCD","collName":" COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING","deptName":"B.E. Electronics and Communication Engineering","results":null,"subjCode":null,"subjName":null,"grade":null,"result":null}]
```

Comment: your code looks perfectly OK to me, what is the problem that you're facing

Comment: When I make the AJAX call I get following error "error: [object Object] status: parsererror er:SyntaxError: Unexpected token a"

Comment: not sure about that particular error, but by taking another look, it seems that your request, and controller are set to receive and return JSON, yet you use return "nameResult"; as if you want the response to resolve to a view (nameResult.jsp). This is surely wrong, most likely the mistake you're after

Comment: Yep, the jsp name is nameResult.jsp. What should I do to update the jsp? From the error I can slightly understand that I need to parse the JSON returned, but don't know how?

Answer (score 1):

Pasting as an answer, easier to format, I suspect two changes needed, one, remove the @ResponseBody from the response

and change controller method to something like

```
 public ModelAndView filterByColl(@RequestBody Mapping oneStudentResult, ModelMap model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("nameResult");
   ...
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

then set the appropriate types in your ajax request, since the response is not json anymore. I think that you'll still face your parsing issue, as it is most likely data related, but this is a way to redirect to a view

Comment: But, My main focus is to update c:forEach. I didn't get any parsing error as I changed the type as html in AJAX. But my C:forEach is not updated yet. I don't even see the alert statement getting called within the success part of AJAX. But controller is working fine.

Comment: Should I need to add anything to ModelAndView other than "nameResult", like the arrayList that needs to be iterated by c:forEach in UI?

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem that I can see, you are using  ***uniqueDeptList*** as the name of the list that is being sent from the controller, an you are using the same name in ***var="uniqueDeptList"***, this probably is casuing an issue, try using a different identifier like ***var="uniqueDeptListCurrentItem"***

```
<select id="byDept" name="byDept" >
    <c:forEach items="${uniqueDeptList}" var="uniqueDeptListCurrentItem">
        <option value="${uniqueDeptListCurrentItem}">
            ${uniqueDeptListCurrentItem}</option >
    </c:forEach >
</select >
```

Comment: When you make that AJAX call, do you fetch the entire HTML page or just the values of ***uniqueDeptList*** in json? If you are doing the former then the c:foreach will get updated automatically, if you are doing the latter, then you cannot update c:foreach. As a matter of fact you cannot update any jsp code using javascript, in order to update the values of the select dropdown you will have to parse the values that you receive in json response, inside of a javascript function and then using javascript you will have to update the values of your dropdown.

Comment: May I know, How can I find out if I'm fetching entire HTML or not? I am using the same AJAX code, that I have posted here.

Comment: I updated the jsp code in question. I guess I am just fetching the dropdown. May I know How can I fetch the entire HTML?

Comment: When you make the ajax call in the browser, you can inspect it's request and response parameters using the javascript console of the browser. Using javascript console look what response you receive, and you will be able to find out whether the response contains only json data or the entire HTML page.

Comment: Change the return type of your Controller method to ***ModelAndView*** and set the view name to your jsp before returning ***ModelAndView*** object. However, if you are going to fetch the entire HTML page, I wonder why are you using AJAX, why not simply reload the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63300/discussion-between-parth6-and-user3705478).